# PHP imagettfext not displaying working

Tags: php, image, text, dynamic, tracker

I used to use a script to change the text on an image via update form.

It worked perfectly at first while I was on a shared host with all modules pre-installed.

I moved to a vps where I had to install everything myself and now the script no longer works.

The php page is able to be displayed but when I update, the text does not show up like it used to.

*Here is an example of the page on the shared host that still works:*
http://nyanpuffle.com/auntarctic/ Password is 1234

*Here is an example of the page on the vps that does not work:*
http://www.clubpenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers/auntarctic/ Password is 1234

Here is a copy of the coding used:

```
<TITLE>Tracker</TITLE>
<body bgcolor="#4b7bb2">
<font face="arial">
<center>
<?php
$submit = $_POST['submit']; // Gets If It has been Submitted
if($submit){ // If submitted do this.
$password = $_POST['password']; // Get the password they submitted
$status = $_POST['status']; // Get the status they submitted
$server = $_POST['server']; // Get the server they submitted
$room = $_POST['room']; // Get the room they submitted
//Now We Secure it.
if($password == "1234"){
//Now We Generate the image and stuff.
$im = imagecreatefrompng("in.png");
// Make RGB Colour For Writing
$colour = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); // I want mine in red(This is black). So I am just
//Gonna find out the rgb code
$font = 'BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf'; // 
//This ^ Is our font, It has to be the exact name and in the right folder.
//Draw Text
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 100, 68, $colour, $font, $status);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 95, 95, $colour, $font, $server);
imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 85, 127, $colour, $font, $room);
//Create Image
imagepng($im,'out.png');
// Destroy - Save Server Resources
imagedestroy($im);
echo "<b> Updated! </b>";
}else
{
echo "<p><b>Incorrect Password!</b></p>";
}
}
//This form remebers what they put, so they dont have to keep typing it in.
// $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] Means Get this document to submit to.
// If you know html this will be familiar.
?>
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" />
<p>Password: <input type="password"  name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo $_POST['password']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Status: <select name="status"> <option value="">Select...</option>
  <option value="Online"> Online</option>
  <option value="Offline"> Offline</option>
  <option value="Tracking..."> Tracking</option>
</select>
</p>
<p>Server: <input type="text" id="server"  name="server" value="<?php echo $_POST['server']; ?>"/></p>
<p>Room: <input type="text" id="room" name="room" value="<?php echo $_POST['room']; ?>"/></p>
<p><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit"/></p>
</form>

<p>Tracker:</p>
<p><img src="out.png" alt="Tracker" /></P>

<a href="http://ClubPenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers"s>Back to Tracker Dashbaord</a>
</center>
```

The VPS is ran on Ubuntu and I have PHP,MYSQL, and Apache installed.

Comment: Could you try a cache-protection mechanism in your call to out.php? Can you update with how things behave after you switch it to <img src="out.png?<?php echo time() ?>"/>?

Comment: I changed the img source that is displayed to the code above, and the text still does not show up.

Comment: The main problem is the text not showing up anymore on the new host

Comment: Can you adjust the code to render the PNG directly and remove the surrounding HTML (don't forget to throw the header content-type at the top)? The point would be to make sure that no weird PHP errors are occurring.

Comment: It's weird because the exact coding works on the shared host (hosted by fatcow)

But when I tried to use it on the VPS, text doesn't update.

Comment: I'll post the code as an answer tomorrow, in the mean time can you make sure that in.png and BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf are also on your VPS server and that their full path is specified (just as dirname(__FILE__).'/' before them)

Comment: Tried full paths, still nothing

Comment: What happens when you load this script directly:
    <?php
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    $im = imagecreatefrompng(dirname(_\_FILE_\_)."/in.png");
    $colour = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
    $font = dirname(_\_FILE_\_).'/BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf';
    imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 100, 68, $colour, $font, 'Testing');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);

Comment: It works when it's loaded directly. http://www.clubpenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers/auntarctic/testing.php But I need it to load the way in the script above because the image is embedded on multiple sites.

Comment: One person said it was because out.png wasn't writable on the web server. But changing the permissions to 777 didn't seem to help either

Comment: EDIT: 
Weird, after trying the permissions changes on another image. The text updated, but not the correct way. It removed the text that was already on the image but didn't replace it with the text I typed in the update form.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code throws `Undefined variable:` errors on all your variables, you should always set variables before using them, this includes $_POST variables, you should enable error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` when developing and then change too `error_reporting(0)` when you upload to a live site then your see the errors that are stopping the processing/updating of the image.

Ive fixed your code with some changes:

```
<?php 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); //remind the browser not to cache the image
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
error_reporting(E_ALL); //Change to 0 when live
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Tracker</title>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="#4b7bb2">
   <font face="arial">
   <center>
 <?php
    $password=''; //pre-set thos vars
    $status='';
    $server='';
    $room='';

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        if($password == "1234"){
            $status = $_POST['status'];
            $server = $_POST['server'];
            $room = $_POST['room'];

            $im = imagecreatefrompng("in.png");
            $colour = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
            $font = 'BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf'; //

            imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 100, 68, $colour, $font, $status);
            imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 95, 95, $colour, $font, $server);
            imagettftext($im, 20, 0, 85, 127, $colour, $font, $room);
            imagepng($im,'out.png');
            imagedestroy($im);
            $result="<b> Updated! </b>";
        }else{
            $result="<p><b>Incorrect Password!</b></p>";
        }
    }
    echo (isset($result))?$result:'';
    ?>
    <form action="" method="POST" />
    <p>Password: <input type="password"  name="password" value="<?php echo htmlentities($password); ?>"/></p>

    <p>Status: <select name="status">
    <option value="">Select...</option>
    <?php 
    echo "<option value=\"Online\""; if($status=='Online'){ echo" selected=\"selected\"";} echo"> Online</option>\n";
    echo "<option value=\"Offline\""; if($status=='Offline'){ echo" selected=\"selected\"";} echo"> Offline</option>\n";
    echo "<option value=\"Tracking...\""; if($status=='Tracking...'){ echo" selected=\"selected\"";} echo"> Tracking</option>\n";
    ?>
    </select>
    </p>

    <p>Server: <input type="text" name="server" value="<?php echo htmlentities($server); ?>"/></p>
    <p>Room: <input type="text" name="room" value="<?php echo htmlentities($room); ?>"/></p>
    <p><input type="submit" name="submit"/></p>
    </form>

    <p>Tracker:</p>
    <p><img src="out.png" alt="Tracker" /></P>

    <a href="http://ClubPenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers"s>Back to Tracker Dashbaord</a>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice the `htmlentities()` & the non use of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in the form.

**EDIT:**
Taken from http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

> The path to the TrueType font you wish to use.
>
> Depending on which version of the GD library PHP is using, when
>   fontfile does not begin with a leading / then .ttf will be appended to
>   the filename and the library will attempt to search for that filename
>   along a library-defined font path.
>
> When using versions of the GD library lower than 2.0.18, a space
>   character, rather than a semicolon, was used as the 'path separator'
>   for different font files. Unintentional use of this feature will
>   result in the warning message: Warning: Could not find/open font. For
>   these affected versions, the only solution is moving the font to a
>   path which does not contain spaces.
>
> In many cases where a font resides in the same directory as the script
>   using it the following trick will alleviate any include problems.

```
<?php
// Set the enviroment variable for GD
putenv('GDFONTPATH=' . realpath('.'));
// Name the font to be used (note the lack of the .ttf extension)
$font = 'BurbankBigRegular-Bold';
?>
```

Comment: The code above works on the shared host as well, but not the VPS. Is there something specific that I need to config in my PHP in order for this to work? Shared Host EXAMPLE: http://nyanpuffle.com/auntarctic VPS EXAMPLE: http://www.clubpenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers/auntarctic/

Comment: Here is my PHP info: http://www.clubpenguincheatsy.com/cptrackers/auntarctic/test.php

Comment: One person said it was because out.png wasn't writable on the web server. But changing the permissions to 777 didn't seem to help either

Comment: Im very sorry but I cannot help, your code and my answerer is the very basic usage of GD, ive had alook at your phpinfo and at first glance it looks ok but can only see that your version of GD is 1.2.42 this maybe the problem as the latest version is 1.5.4 http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html like other's have said make sure you permissions are correct. if your apache handlers are DSO mode change it too suPHP if you can so your script is not run as (nobody) but as your hosting username then chmod 0755 for folders & 0644 for files, apart from that I have no idea whats wrong. sorry

Comment: Yeah it's probably something simple. I'm thinking it has to do with me just moving the database and directories to the new server. You wouldn't happen to know any other way to update images with an update form would you?

Comment: I got this from error report: Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/cptrackers/auntarctic/index.php on line 34 Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/cptrackers/auntarctic/index.php on line 35 Warning: imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/cptrackers/auntarctic/index.php on line 36

Comment: make sure the font exists on the server and is accessible, if it does try renaming it or try a different font like the arial. I could not find any mention of the `FreeType library` in your php not sure if it shows in info output, but is required by GD. http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$font = 'BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf';
```

replace with :

```
define ("_DOC_ROOT", dirname( __FILE__ ) ."/" );
$font = _DOC_ROOT.'dir_u_know/dir_u_know/BurbankBigRegular-Bold.ttf';
```